# How to check if you are authenticated with gcloud auth login or not with Python

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I tried doing this way, but it gave an error

```
import os

creds_file_path = os.path.expanduser("~/.config/gcloud/credentials")
if os.path.isfile(creds_file_path):
    print("You are authenticated with gcloud auth login.")
else:
    print("You are not authenticated with gcloud auth login.")
```

This gives

```
No such file or directory
```

Is there any other way without using external libraries?

Comment: The need is to launch a Python app that interact with GCP services ?

Comment: Why do you need to know this information? And why don't you use the Google Cloud client library?

Comment: I am developing a script, for automating several lines of code. In order to do that I need to log in to google cloud. The reason I want to do it without the Google Cloud library is that others will be using my script and I don't want each of them to install a library before running the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you want create a Python script that access to Google Cloud, you only have to set the following env var to your Service Account Json key file path :

```bash
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/your_folder/sa_key.json
```

Then you can launch the main file containing the entry point to your Python script.